# Integration of Denodo with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, denodo

Have a requirement to read data from Denodo (Data virtualization) tool to AWS S3 bucket. Has anyone done such integration. If so, what is the best practice/process to integrate Denodo with AWS S3 bucket. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://community.denodo.com/kb/en/view/document/How%20to%20integrate%20Amazon%20S3%20with%20the%20Denodo%20Platform?tag=Data+Sources) it looks like the custom wrapper is the preferred option.  Make sure to install it on all nodes in your environment/cluster individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read from denodo and write to S3, you need another tool to run this task. Denodo is "just" a database. You can query denodo via JDBC or ODBC like any other database.

For example use python + sqlalchemy (https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/document/denodoconnects/8.0/en/Denodo%20Dialect%20for%20SQLAlchemy%20-%20User%20Manual) to query data from denodo. Your python program has to write the data to AWS S3 afterwards. You could use boto3 python-package to write to S3.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you're looking to integrate Denodo with AWS S3.

You can achieve this by using the Denodo Distributed File System Custom Wrapper.

For detailed steps, please refer to the official documentation on connecting to an AWS S3 bucket from the Denodo Platform [here](https://community.denodo.com/kb/en/view/document/How%20to%20integrate%20Amazon%20S3%20with%20Denodo%20Distributed%20File%20System%20Custom%20Wrapper).

Hope this helps!